# Is it possible using xcodebuild from the command line to build incrementally like the Xcode frontend?

Tags: xcode, bash, xcodebuild

I develop a macOS application and, for various reasons, I need a script to compile it from the command line. This works, but I have noticed that it compiles always like if the project had just been cleaned, that is, everything from scratch. Even if I don't make any modification to the project, it builds from the beginning and for this reason it takes a lot of time. My command is:

```
sudo -u $loggedInUser xcodebuild -project "${REPO_DIR}/MyProj.xcodeproj" -alltargets -configuration Release
```

Perhaps I can specify this requirement with an argument ? I hope somebody can bring me in the right direction. Thanks for your attention.